# Response.Write(RSS) causes Javascript-exception: " Unspecified error" (IIS 7.5)

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, xml, rss

I'm attempting to output my own RSS-feed using ASP.NET with `Response.Write`. The program code itself doesn't result in an error/exception. But when outputting using `Response.Write` i'm getting an error in the JS-Script `HttpErrorpagesscript`. Error i'm recieving is `Runtime error Microsoft JScript: Unspecified Error`.

It happens on the following line:

```
function initMoreInfo(infoBlockID)
{
   var bElement = document.createElement("A"); 
   bElement.innerText = L_MOREINFO_TEXT; <--- Break happens here
   bElement.href = "javascript:expandCollapse(\'infoBlockID\', true);";
   moreInfoContainer.appendChild(bElement);
}
```

I don't know the origin  of the error so i'm supplying the C# for outputting the xml.

```
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
        {
            // Write startelement
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            //Write elementRSS
            writer.WriteStartElement("rss");
            //Write channel
            writer.WriteStartElement("channel");
            //Write title
            writer.WriteElementString("title","RSS-Feed svranken");
            //Write Ttl
            writer.WriteElementString("ttl","1");

            foreach (SyndicationItem rssItem in syndFeed.Items.OrderByDescending(x => x.PublishDate).Take(25))
            {

                writer.WriteStartElement("item");

                //Write Elements
                writer.WriteElementString("PubDate", rssItem.PublishDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                writer.WriteElementString("title", rssItem.Title.Text);
                writer.WriteElementString("description", rssItem.Summary.Text);
                writer.WriteElementString("link", rssItem.Id.ToString());

                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        Response.Write(builder.ToString());
```

Does anyone spot the error? What am i missing here?

Thank you for your time

**Note:** The Javascript i supplied above is not part of my solution. I think its automatically generated by my local IIS.

**UPDATE:** IISExpress produces the same error as doest the visual studio development server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

The Origin lied in the faulty way of outputting RSS. After some searches/fixes i've come up with the following working solution:

So the correct code is

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/rss+xml";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(builder.ToString());
        xmlDoc.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.End();
```

With kind regards